# How to save time text when clicking on a button?

Tags: objective-c, time, clock

I am working on an app in Xcode and I want to know how to do this: when I click on a button, and then the clock display on a label, it saves the text (making a record of the clock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get date / Show date within text field / Write date to file on desktop:

```
- (IBAction)theButton:(id)sender {
    NSString * currentDate = [[NSDate date] description];
    [theLabel setStringValue:currentDate];
    [currentDate writeToFile:@"/Users/Anne/Desktop/log.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:NULL];
}
```

Result:

> 2011-04-28 20:18:02 +0200

Get time / Show time within text field / Write time to file on desktop:

```
- (IBAction)theButton:(id)sender {
    NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *currentTime = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
    [theLabel setStringValue:currentTime];
    [currentTime writeToFile:@"/Users/Anne/Desktop/log.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:NULL];
}
```

Result:

> 08:17:41

Note: You change the date to any format by using NSDateFormatter.

Comment: mine say +0000 and your say +0200  how do i change that?

Comment: The `+0200` refers to the time-zone ofset from UTC. During summer The Netherlands is within the CEST time-zone and CEST is equal to UTC + 2 hour. In other words, you're probably within the UTC time-zone.

Comment: Denmark is currently indeed CET. Make sure the time-zone is set correctly on your Mac. Check: System Preferences > Date & Time > Time Zone